# How to use feature detection to know if browser supports border-radius? (Including IE9)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, css, feature-detection

I've seen plenty of examples for detecting support for border radius using something like:

```
var cssAttributeNames = ['BorderRadius', 'MozBorderRadius', 'WebkitBorderRadius', 'OBorderRadius', 'KhtmlBorderRadius']; 
for (var i = 0; i < cssAttributeNames.length; i++) {
    var attributeName = cssAttributeNames[i];
    if (window.document.body.style[attributeName] !== undefined) {
        this._useCss = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work for IE9, which does support border-radius. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it - the detection array needs 'borderRadius' added  - it's case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a Javascript library used to detect HTML5 features (including `border-radius`), so if you're looking for a ready made solution, check that out.

Comment: Had not seen this before. It's kind of awesome.