# Feature Detection for working elliptical border radius

Tags: javascript, css

I am writing a small page that uses elliptical border radius, which works inconsistently across browsers (of course) and sometimes interacts badly with other things (namely, old Safari, old Firefox and maybe Opera), which don't properly clip the content when `using overflow:hidden`.

What is the best way to detect a working elliptical radius implementation? 
It would appear UA sniffing is the only way it actually works, but I feel dirty about it, and frankly I have no clue which versions I should consider working or not.

I suspect this should be something possible with Modernizr but I haven't found documentation about it.

Notice this is *not* the same issue as [for How can I replace my old browser check with a feature detection check for border-radius without modernizr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336453/for-how-can-i-replace-my-old-browser-check-with-a-feature-detection-check-for-bo) , these browsers say they support border-radius and indeed they do, but they do it in a broken way WRT elliptical borders and/or clipping.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue? And perhaps add some screenshots.

Comment: sure, http://jsfiddle.net/9AFME/4/ is some sample code, picture at http://imgur.com/8smQYWU  demonstrates the issue with FF 3.6, not sure at what point it starts working in FF. I have seen the issue with older safari versions too, but I can't seem to reproduce it on 5.1 ATM.

Comment: Firefox 3.6 is extremely old (there's less than 1% of users still using it). The [border-radius clipping bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=459144) was fixed on Firefox 4, if I recall correctly. You could workaround the bug by setting the image as a background-image, though stopping support for Firefox 3.6 probably would not hurt. From the screenshot you give though, I don't think Firefox 3.6 had any issue with the elliptical radius itself. Can't say much about Safari though as I don't use Mac.

Comment: sure, but I'd rather handle these someway if possible, it takes one line of javascript to check browser version, I just preferred to use feature detection if possible.

Comment: I'd use JavaScript to check version or use an alternative technique (e.g. set as background), you can't feature detect a bug, and it's not worth your time thinking too much for the less than 1% users that uses outdated browser.