# How to check if browser supports css3 rounded corners and svg

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, css

Basically i have web site where i want to check if client browser supports rounded corners and svg as well and if not i want to show the message that for best user experience is better to use the latest browser.

So how could i check for that?

**UPDATE:**

I just found such library called Modernizr, is it possible to us that to check for that things?

Comment: I thought the whole "best viewed with such-and-such browser" thing went out of style when Netscape died.

Comment: See this post. Ignore the accepted answer and look at some of the other solutions that use jquery or straight javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077/the-best-way-of-checking-for-moz-border-radius-support

Comment: But I also agree with @mblase75. "The best user experience" never is to download and install something else, that's "the best developer experience"

Comment: @mblase75 may be after IE will die it will be true.

Comment: @Chris Haas i dont want to spend tie and develop for ie 6 and ie 7, i just want to say users that if they want better experience they may just get better browser.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using Modernizr; I've found this the easiest way to detect features: [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)

On a side note, you can provide some CSS3 features to IE users by using CSS3 Pie. This includes an HTC file on the page that replicates these effects: [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com)

Comment: Would defintly go with Modernizr! Just what you want, it will have a class in the html tag that you can apply any CSS too.

Comment: as i understand Modernizr will generate what client browser does not support and add that to <HTML `here`> and on page load complete i need to check for that things on client and apply related fix?